# How do I find my paypal pro api string in opencart?

Tags: paypal, opencart

How do I find my paypal pro api string in opencart?
I have looked everywhere and even posted this question on opencart forum but I haven't gotten a single answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your trying to make an API Request?

This will help you:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-process-credit-cards-with-paypal-payments-pro-using-php/

And if you are looking for your API-Signature do the following:

```
Login to your account at paypal.com
Choose Profile
Left Column..choose API Access
then
VIEW code generated.
User name , password and 56-character API Signature Code
should now show.. if it doesn't, delete and generate another 
OR
contact paypal for help.
```

Hope this helps